# Migrate existing spring app to spring-boot, manually configure spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an existing spring 3.1.4 application that works fine and boots up ok on its own. I currently start the spring context manually in a main class of my own. This is NOT a spring-mvc app, it does not contain any servlets, web.xml nor does it generate a WAR. It just produces a JAR for an integration backend.

I would like "wrap" this legacy application and launch it with spring-boot. However I am having trouble figuring out how to do this as all the examples seem to assume creating a "new" application.

1) I have my existing applicationContext.xml file with my existing spring app bean declarations in it

2) What is the minimum set of new bean configs that I need to add to my existing Spring applicationContext.xml file in order to have spring-boot w/ tomcat launched and load all of my existing beans into the spring-boot wrapped context?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: If it isn't a web app then why use Spring Boot with Tomcat? Just don't use the web dependency and let spring boot create the context for you. Spring Boot doen't require to be a web based application. You can use it for command line apps as well.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a chapter dedicated to [Converting an existing application to Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot) in the Spring Boot reference guide.

Basically you need to add the Spring Boot dependencies and then implement the main entry point like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class MySpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

However, this will also trigger Spring Boot's auto-configuration based upon (among other things) available classes and configured beans. You might want to [disable certain auto-configurations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration). To exclude DataSource and Hibernate JPA auto-configuration, use:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Comment: Using the starter-web dependency, which is driving me nuts, as it wants some DataSource which I don't need, get errors like "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE."  I want an properly configured Tomcat embedded and hooked up to WSSpringServlet so I can register some custom SOAP services.

Comment: So followed this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot and I get this "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE" error. I have absolutely no need for a database other than what I have configured in my existing spring context sources that I am adding to the application as noted in the doc.

Comment: Spring Boot's auto-configuration inspects (among other things) available classes and configured beans. You probably have an (used) dependency or a (misconfigured) bean that triggers some auto-configuration that needs a datasource. For more details about the auto-configuration classes see the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#auto-configuration-classes).

Comment: Exclude the `tomcat-jdbc` package.

Comment: I tried this to no avail, same error  `    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
     exclude(module: 'tomcat-jdbc')
    }` there error is when wiring this bean "HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"

Comment: oh, just saw the edited comment above regarding exclusions, let me try that

Comment: The answer is: @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Glad we could help! I updated my answer accordingly. However, you might want to add your own answer detailing your solution. Either way, please accept any answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: In my case the org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer was not found; so I excluded BatchAutoConfiguration; thanks for this great post; S.