# Spring Security logins fail when migrating Spring mvc projects to Spring boot

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, migrate

I migrated a working Spring mvc project to Spring boot. Refer to Section 81.3 of this [document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409231/migrate-existing-spring-app-to-spring-boot-manually-configure-spring-boot). Modules are working properly, but SpringSecurity can not login.

In the open when the home page will jump to the login page, and then log in after the home page and login page repeatedly redirects are 302 HTTP response, and then an error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

After debugging, when I log on Custom UserDetailsService can correctly find and return UserDetails, custom SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler also called onAuthenticationSuccess normally, <s>but in the filter chain in a call FilterSecurityInterceptor this filter, SpringSecurity login status is cleared, I And does not call logout of the HTTP request.</s> 
I carefully check that in the set `create-session = "stateless"` clear the login status is normal, but it seems that my application can not be properly re-authorized. After the request has been `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().GetAuthentication().GetPrincipal()` has been anonymousUesr (Cookies correctly passed `loginKey = b3668242-574a-498e-bd03-243e28dc805c; SESSIONID_HAP = 98963370-8561-40a2-9898-a5e80f7d1186`).

This project is more complex, the following is an important part of the configuration and code, and their role is basically the original and the equivalent.

SpringBootConfigure.java SpringBoot enter point.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@ImportResource({"classpath:/spring/applicationContext*.xml","classpath:/spring/appServlet/servlet*.xml"})
public class SpringBootConfigure {
...
}
```

spring security xml config

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/verifiCode" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/common/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/boot/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html"/>


    <form-login login-page='/login' authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailureHandler"/>
    <custom-filter ref="captchaVerifierFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>

    <logout logout-url="/logout"/>

    <headers defaults-disabled="true">
        <cache-control/>
    </headers>
</http>

<beans:bean id="loginFailureHandler" class="com.hand.hap.security.LoginFailureHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordManager"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="captchaVerifierFilter" class="com.hand.hap.security.CaptchaVerifierFilter">
    <beans:property name="captchaField" value="verifiCode"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="com.hand.hap.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index"/>
</beans:bean>
```