# How to migrate spring 1.2.6 application to Spring boot ? Are there any migration tools for the same

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a legacy application which uses spring 1.2.6. How to I migrate it to the latest spring boot. Are there any migration tool available for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has already been answered here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409231/migrate-existing-spring-app-to-spring-boot-manually-configure-spring-boot

Comment: Manually and take babysteps. I would start by leaving it as is and upgrade to the latests Spring 1.2.x version, then 2.0, 2.5 until you are on a Spring Boot supported version and then introduce Spring Boot. That way you can change things step by step instead of having to cope with all the massive changes at once. (Hmm maybe I should really finish that blog-post about this subject).

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready made guide for upgrading, only some solid advice on the same.

## TL; DR;

1. Take baby steps

   - First upgrade Spring 1.2, 2.0, 2.5 etc.
2. When you have a version of Spring that is supported by Spring Boot use that Spring Boot version to manage your dependencies
3. Use your existing configuration and let Spring Boot bootstrap your application
4. Migrate your configuration to use Spring Boot auto-configuration features

After each step verify your application still does what it should do. Either by manually verifying it or by creating a good test-harness (which I already hope is more or less in place!).

## Upgrading Spring to Spring Boot

You are one quite an old version of Spring, but generally Spring is quite backwards compatible. Also remember you have a running and working application and you want to keep it that way.

Upgrading is taking baby steps. one at time and after each step verify that your application is still behaving correctly.

### Upgrade Spring

Start by upgrading to the latest Spring 1.2.x version (that should be mostly painless) then upgrade to the next major version (2.0, 2.5 etc.).  It might also be that you need to upgrade versions of supporting libraries along side upgrading Spring due to Spring dropping support for it (like old versions of Hibernate, Velocity, Jackson etc.).

### Use Spring Boot to Manage Dependencies

When you are on a version that supports Spring Boot start to use Spring Boot to manage your dependencies, this will cleanup your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` considerably. Also keep using your current configuration all along, don't try to migrate your XML based configuration to Java based Config in one go (again baby-steps).

### Use Spring Boot to launch the application but keep your own configuration

After that run your application with Spring Boot, using your own configuration (using `@ImportResource`). Remember you had a running and working application/configuration.

### Final steps

Then you can do 1 of 2 things, either keep upgrading to the latest version of Spring Boot (whilst keeping your existing configuration) or migrate your configuration (partially) to Java based config and take advantage of the Spring Boot auto-configuration features.

**Note:** 2 years ago I did [a presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_WIvCsY6G0) about this very exact subject taking all of these steps one by one.