# How do I convert this code from Spring to Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mitreid-connect

I have cut and pasted an  MVC MitreID Spring web app into a basic boot web app. When I try and run it I get:

```
A component required a bean named 'namedAdmins' that could not be found
```

The code is:

```
import org.mitre.openid.connect.client.OIDCAuthenticationFilter;
import org.mitre.openid.connect.client.SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority;
@RestController
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Autowired
private OIDCAuthenticationFilter filter;

@Resource(name = "namedAdmins")
private Set<SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority> admins;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

This was just the Spring code with me changing @controller to @restcontroller.

this is in servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="openIdConnectAuthenticationProvider" class="org.mitre.openid.connect.client.OIDCAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authoritiesMapper">
        <bean class="org.mitre.openid.connect.client.NamedAdminAuthoritiesMapper">
            <property name="admins" ref="namedAdmins" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<util:set id="namedAdmins" value-type="org.mitre.openid.connect.client.SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority">

    <bean class="org.mitre.openid.connect.client.SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority">
        <constructor-arg name="subject" value="90342.ASDFJWFA" />
        <constructor-arg name="issuer" value="http://192.168.1.114:8080/openid-connect-server-webapp/" />
    </bean>
</util:set>
```

Can anyone please get me started on what else I need to change/where to look to get the bean recognised?
This is in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
    <artifactId>openid-connect-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409231/migrate-existing-spring-app-to-spring-boot-manually-configure-spring-boot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate existing spring app to spring-boot, manually configure spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409231/migrate-existing-spring-app-to-spring-boot-manually-configure-spring-boot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `servlet-context.xml` is not included in Spring Boot application. Either import it with `@ImportResource` annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("servlet-context.xml")
public class MyApp {
  // ...
}
```

or convert this XML to a new Java configuration class, which would be the preferred approach:

```
@Configuration
public class MitreConfig {

  @Bean
  public Set<SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority> namedAdmins() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added in `@ImportResource("classpath*:servlet-context.xml")` but same error.

Comment: @schoon the bean was most likely not registered, maybe the XML wasn't processed?

Comment: How would I get it to be processed? Sorry: I am a beginner at this.

Comment: @schoon Where is `servlet-context.xml` located in your WAR/JAR? Is it packaged in the default package?

Comment: it is in: `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/`. Not sure about default. How Do I tell?

Comment: @schoon move it to `src/main/resources`